# How to create a new array with the same content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I use [an external library](https://help.aimylogic.com/docs/en/advanced/array_functions) to iterate over the array. It has the `next()` function to go to the next array item and returns `false` if there is no next item. If the `next()` is called the first time, then it returns the first item.

But here is how it works -

```
var a = ['item1'];
a.next(); // 'item1' is returned
...
a = ['item1']; // it could be called several times
a.next(); // false is returned, but 'item1' is expected
```

Is there any way to make `a` array to be treated as new array by `next()` function?
I tried to add new elements to `a` (`a.push(' ')`) and it works well, but then I have to deal with an empty array elements.

Comment: Without knowing which library you use and how that works, it's nigh impossible to tell you how to use it as expected.

Comment: @VLAZ, I've added the link. I am afraid it will not help - the source code is not available.

Comment: You can use `a.first()` to get the first item, and `a.next()` subsequent to that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I don't use `a.first()` currently and always use `a.next`, since usage of `a.first()` will complicate the code. 
(this is not pure code, I build `the code` from the blocks)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one dimensional array you could probably do something like:

```
let newArray = [...oldArray];
```

This would create a new array.

Can I ask you why you are using an external library to map over an array?

Comment: Thanks. Can I use `newArray = [...'item1']`? I receive the following error - `Expected an operand but found .`

Comment: you can use [...['item1']].

what you suggested would result in ['i', 't', 'e', 'm', '1']

`[...[1], 2,3]` = `[1,2,3]`
`{...{a:1, b: 2},c: 3}` = `{a:1,b:2, c:3}`

Comment: Got it, thank you. Anyway, it doesn't work - the same error is returned. Probably because of ecmascript 5.

Comment: hmmmm it's really strange - I'm not sure why the library would refer that as the same array. Try to reassign the variable as well, so:

var a = ['item']
...
var a = new Array(...a)

There is no way this doesn't separate the arrays, unless you are operating on a nested array in which case only the top level is re-assigned.

If this doesn't work post more code - preferably complete implementation in something like codesandbox.

write var again - var is re-assigneable. let and const is not

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator to create a shallow copy of that array.

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [...a];

a.push(4);

console.log("a = " + a);
console.log("b = " + b);
```